# Error "not all arguments converted during string formatting" while inserting in Database MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have an SQL query which is giving an error:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO `DB` (`ban`, `dntr`, `usrnm`, `id`, `dis`)  VALUES (1,0,?,?,?)",(param1,param2,param3,))
```

I don't want to use `%s` in query because it is prone to SQL injection and I am taking input from users.

Answer (score 2):

mysqlclient uses `%s` as the placeholder (see the [example in the docs](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#some-examples)).

Change your code to the following:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO `DB` (`ban`, `dntr`, `usrnm`, `id`, `dis`)  VALUES (1,0,%s,%s,%s)", (param1,param2,param3,))
```

You're right to be concerned about SQL injection, but the above is OK. You are still using `execute` with parameters, so they will be escaped.

The thing you shouldn't do is `cur.execute(query % parameters, [])`. This is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Well i got SQLi in my DB by some attacker in this statement:

`await cur.execute("""UPDATE DB SET hwid=%s where discid=%s""",(nhwd,message.author.id))`

Thats y i raised the issue.

Comment: That code shouldn't be vulnerable to SQL injection. I assumed you were using `mysqlclient` but I see you're using `await`. Perhaps you are mistaken that it was that query that was vulnerable, or perhaps there is a bug in the library you are using.

Comment: I am using aiomysql for MySQL DB using discord.py , in which they are adding and updating the UID by themselves.
For example:
`$cmd 123`
123 will be added to DB
`$updt 321`
321 will be updated in place of 123

Comment: As I said, it looks like either you're mistaken and your attacker used a different query, or there's a bug in aiomysql (less likely in my opinion).